# EFI Application Erorr Write Protected

Tags: filesystems, firmware, uefi, edk2

I tried to do some write/read operations on filesystems that I have enumerated for. The problem is when I want to write to other volumes rather than my self (fs0), it will return `WRITE PROTECTED` Error.

```
 ... Enumerated and opened all available volumes successfuly

 efiStatus = root->Open(root, &token, L"xxx", EFI_FILE_MODE_READ | EFI_FILE_MODE_WRITE | EFI_FILE_MODE_CREATE, 0);
    
    if (efiStatus == EFI_SUCCESS)
    {
        char* myStr = "Sample Content";
        UINTN myStrSize = strlenEx(myStr);

        efiStatus = token->Write(token, &myStrSize, myStr);
        if (efiStatus != EFI_SUCCESS)
        {
            Print(L"[X] ! Error [%r]!\n", efiStatus);
        }
        Print(L"Found Some\n", efiStatus);
    }
```

I Also tried `ShellCreateDirectory`, `ShellWriteFile`. Do I really can access write hard disk (pci) from EFI Application?

EDIT:

`drivers` command output:

```
                T   D
D           Y C I
R           P F A
V  VERSION  E G G #D #C DRIVER NAME                         IMAGE NAME
== ======== = = = == == =================================== ==========
43 00000014 D - -  1  - AMI USB Driver                      Uhcd
45 00000014 B - -  1  4 USB bus                             Uhcd
46 00000002 D - -  3  - USB Hid driver                      Uhcd
47 00000001 D - -  1  - USB Mass Storage driver             Uhcd
85 00010000 ? - -  -  - AMI ExFat Driver                    EXFAT
86 00010000 D - -  5  - AMI NTFS Driver                     NTFS
89 00000001 D - -  2  - <null string>                       MouseDriver
8B 00000001 B - -  1  3 AMI AHCI BUS Driver                 Ahci
8F 00000001 ? - -  -  - AMI NVMe BUS Driver                 Nvme
123 00000010 D - -  1  - Serial ATA Controller Initializatio SataController
12E 00000010 B - -  1  1 AMI Console Splitter Text Out Drive ConSplitter
12F 00000010 B - -  1  1 AMI Console Splitter Text In Driver ConSplitter
130 00000010 B - -  1  1 AMI Console Splitter Pointer Driver ConSplitter
133 00000010 D - -  1  - AMI Graphic Console Driver          GraphicsConsole
134 0000000A D - - 15  - Generic Disk I/O Driver             DiskIoDxe
135 0000000B B - -  3 11 Partition Driver(MBR/GPT/El Torito) PartitionDxe
137 00000000 ? - -  -  - Integrated Touch Driver             IntegratedTouch
13A 00000010 B - -  1  5 AMI Generic LPC Super I/O Driver    GenericSio
13C 00A50110 B - -  1 15 AMI PCI Bus Driver                  PciBus
13E 00000010 ? - -  -  - AMI PS/2 Driver                     Ps2Main
13F 00000000 ? - -  -  - DNS Network Service Driver          DnsDxe
140 00000000 ? - -  -  - DNS Network Service Driver          DnsDxe
145 0000000A D - -  2  - FAT File System Driver              Fat
147 00010001 ? - -  -  - AMI ISO9660 File System Driver      FsIso9660
149 00000001 ? - -  -  - <null string>                       PcieSataController
14A 00000001 ? - -  -  - <null string>                       PcieSataController
14B 0000001B B - -  1  3 Intel(R) RST 16.0.2.3402 RAID Drive RaidDriver
159 09000432 B - -  1  1 Intel(R) GOP Driver [9.0.1074]      MemoryMapped(0x3,0x845F3018,0x846040D8)
```

Comment: Are the corresponding BlockIo protocols marked as ReadOnly (check the BlockIo->Media->ReadOnly flag)?

Comment: @MiSimon I tried and its not Readonly, but still I cant write

Comment: So, you can write to fs0, right? but you cannot write to others?

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin what other FS ids do you have on your platform?

Comment: @Alex Yes I can write on fs0, but not the others. I tested on a PC that installed Windows on it, it has 4 volumes, fs1 is C:\\ Volume, fs2 D:\\, fs3 F:\\, fs4 E:\\. I want to write on fs1 which is Windows C volume.

Comment: @Alex, Even with Shell command line I can't edit or remove the files on ther FS ids. it says either 'Write Protected' or 'Unable to create' when using mkdir

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin are you sure that those volumes has fs id? Can you update your question with a screenshot of your device table from uefi shell? My guess that you have only one FS0 and the rest are BLK01...02 etc...

Comment: If you update your question please provide the output of the "drivers" efi shell command, the windows partitions maybe using NTFS and not FAT32.

Comment: @MiSimon I added the output

Comment: There is an NTFS driver in the list (#86), this driver might not be able to write to the file systems.

Comment: @MiSimon Can UEFI:NTFS work on this ?

Comment: If you have a driver that supports writing to NTFS then yes, take a look at the refind project (https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) they have efi drivers for many file systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My educated guess is that you trying to access NTFS volume (since you talked about Windows partitions) and **NTFS is not supported** by UEFI (by default). At least, I haven't seen any firmware that does. **UEFI supports FAT32 file systems only.**

If you drop into UEFI shell on your platform you should see the **"Mapping table"** (see the sample picture below), if there is a device labeled **"FS0"**. This indicates that the firmware detected the disk, discovered the partition, and was able **to mount the file system**. The rest of the volumes labeled as BLK, which means UEFI can give the access using BlockIO Protocol only. No FS Protocol support.

[image: Here is an example of the mapping table]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tested on a FAT32 volume and it worked fine on creating a Folder. is there anyway to write on NTFS? as I mentioned above about UEFI:NTFS?

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin That’s I don't know. Newer seen UEFI firmware with NTFS support.